# Удаление строк в DataFrame по условию

Tags: python, pandas

Есть примерно такой датафрейм:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                   'time_unix': [int(1659608881), int(1659608180), int(1659604885), int(1659608362)]})
```

Нужно удалить строки, где в ячейке с юникс временем разница с текущим временем составляет больше n секунд.
Вроде и просто должно быть, но никак не соображу.

Answer (score 2):

Да, всё довольно просто. Только проще действовать наоборот - **оставить** в датафрейме записи по **обратному условию**. Непонятно только разница абсолютная (плюс и минус) или какая должна быть, для абсолютной так:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                   'time_unix': [int(1659608881), int(1659608180), int(1659604885), int(1659608362)]})
n = 2000
df = df[(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()-df.time_unix).abs() <= n]
df
```

Вывод на данный момент:

```py
    column1 time_unix
0   a   1659608881
```

По дополнительному условию:

```py
df = df[(df.time_unix == 0) | 
        ((datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()-df.time_unix).abs() <= n)]
```

Обратите внимание, что условия берутся в скобки и используются бинарные операции (в данном случае `|`), а не логические (`or`).

Comment: Отлично, то что надо. Но нюанс один забыл) Все тоже самое, но только нужно оставить (не трогать) строки, где значение в колонке time_unix = 0.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.